# after installation of sonarlint in spring too suit 4 i am getting error An internal error occurred during: "Initialize Language Servers for

Tags: spring-boot, initialization, sonarlint-eclipse, typescript-language-server

I have installed sonarlint in my spring boot suit and bind the projects. after binding projects whenever I am opening any file(java or html), I am getting following error:-

An internal error occurred during: "Initialize Language Servers for indentallocate.html".
org/eclipse/lsp4j/jsonrpc/ResponseErrorException

I installed sonarlint for find out the detect and fix quality issues. it analyze succesfully but when i restarted my spring boot suit, it started giving error for initialize Language Servers

Comment: I am facing another problem. now no file in opening in editor. Just cross sign visible at the top

Comment: I would suggest asking on their community [forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/sl/eclipse/34) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a conflict between the version of lsp4j embedded into SonarLint, and the one used by lsp4e.

A [ticket](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SLE-793) has been created on the SonarLint side.